# LDAP - Active Directory - Can/Should I Use A Class?

Tags: class, vba, ms-access, active-directory, ldap

My original purpose with LDAP was to return all active members of a specified group that is currently an active employee.

I came to this solution:

```
Public Const ADConString = "Provider=ADsDSOObject;
                            Encrypt Password=False;
                            Integrated Security=SSPI;
                            Data Source=
                            LDAP://Domain:Numbers/DC=ROOT,
                            DC=Someplace,OU=SomePlace;
                            Mode=Read
                            Bind Flags=0;ADSI Flag=-2147483648"


Public Function getActiveDirectoryGroup(groupName As String)

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim test As Variant

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open ADConString 

cmd.CommandText = 
      "SELECT sn,adspath,cn,givenname,userAccountControl 
          FROM 'LDAP://RootPlace _
          "WHERE MemberOf='cn=" & groupName & 
          ",CN=SomePlace,DC=KMC,DC=SomePlace' " & _
          "AND userAccountControl<>514
           AND sn <>'name1' AND sn <>'name2' 
           AND sn           <>'name3' " & _
          "ORDER BY givenname"

Debug.Print cmd.CommandText

cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

Set rs = cmd.execute
groupPath = rs.Fields("adspath").Value
Do While Not rs.EOF
    'Debug.Print rs.Fields("adspath").Value
    Debug.Print rs.Fields("givenname").Value & " " 
        & rs.Fields("sn").Value & "     " 
        & rs.Fields("userAccountControl")
    'Debug.Print rs.Fields("cn").Value

rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Function
```

Now, this solution works if you pass it a group, but I would like to expand it so someone could grab only active members or get rid of the `sn <>'name1' AND sn <>'name2' AND sn<>'name3'` conditionals.

So far I've built this class

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private pADConnectionString As String
Private pRootLocation As String
Private pGroupName As String
Private Sub class_Initialize()
     pADConnectionString = "Provider=ADsDSOObject;
                            Encrypt Password=False;
                            Integrated Security=SSPI;
                            Data Source=
                            LDAP://Domain:Numbers/DC=ROOT,
                            DC=Someplace,OU=SomePlace;
                            Mode=Read
                            Bind Flags=0;ADSI Flag=-2147483648"

pRootLocation = getNC()



End Sub
Sub retreiveUsers()

End Sub
Public Property Get ADConnectionString() As Double
    ADConnectionString = pADConnectionString
End Property
Public Property Let ADConnectionString(connectionString As Double)
    pADConnectionString = connectionString
End Property
Function getNC()
    Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    getNC = objRoot.Get("defaultNamingContext")
End Function
Public Property Get groupName() As String
    groupName = pGroupName
End Property
Public Property Let groupName(group As String)
    pGroupName = group
End Property
```

I am a bit rusty on classes and I am not quite sure how to introduce a dynamic `WHERE` statement into this class. So, should I continue down this path, and if so what sorts of solutions could I consider for handling the `WHERE` clause?

I was thinking about using something sloppy, such as a setter that appends what the user sends to what is already applied to a new `whereStatement` private variable, that way it could keep appending to the `WHERE` clause. My concern there is that, short of a complete clear I would not be able to remove individual conditional statements such as `sn<>'Name1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `overload` the function.
Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
Function getActiveDirectoryGroup(Optional groupName as string)

    Dim sQuery as string        

    if LenB(groupname) = 0 then 
        sQuery = "<general sql statement>"
    else
        sQuery = "<sql statement with conditions>"
    end if 

End Function
```

**Edit**

Function overloading like you find it in more extensive OOP languages such as C++, C# and Java is not possible in VBA.
However, using the Optional parameter, you can simulate the behaviour.

Comment: My goal was to dynamically change what users got returned. Sometimes I would like to have a group returned with inactive users that have the words abc in there name, but other times I would want to do something completely different. My goal with the class was to allow the user to dynamically build what they wanted with ease. The problem I have with this solution is that it would eventually lead to a very nested if statement tree and a massive amount of optional values.

Comment: Vba doesn't support inheritance, so you can't make one base class to have a number of customized classes inherit from it. The only way I see the possibility to create a reusable class without customization is to pass the entire query string to the class method and compose the query string in the callibg functions. And/or as you mentioned, pass the where clause as a parameter.

Comment: This way, you can still use the code I provided. The class method can standard give you the entire result set, with the where clause as optional parameter. This way, you won't have numerous conditions.

Comment: @KimGysen, I ended up choosing this answer because the class got too complicated for the little bit of functionality it would be creating. Instead I built many basic functions that will fulfill the requirements.

Comment: I think that's a logical solution. The concept of a static class that I mentioned below may interest you as well. Whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Classes in VBA offer very little advantage over standard modules, especially for the kind of thing you are trying to do here. In VBA, I think of classes as a way of grouping together closely related functions/methods and properties into a reusable "container". With most of my classes, I start out getting what I need in a standard module and then I turn it into a class after the fact. With a class you can set a bunch of properties and then run one of the methods, whereas with modules you need to pass in all the properties as arguments or else use global variables or maybe a custom type or class just to hold properties. So yes, classes have a small advantage there, but mostly for the programmer. In your case, a class doesn't provide any feature that a standard module doesn't provide.

If you continue with your class idea which is certainly an acceptable proposition, I think you should actually move ahead with the "sloppy" idea you presented at the end of your question. I think this could be called a "predicate builder" method/function. If you want the ability to remove specific criteria without clearing the whole thing, you'll have to build this in yourself. When you add a criteria using your predicate builder function, just put each additional criteria into some kind of container object like a fabricated ADO Recordset, a Dictionary object, or an Array. This way you can always look through the structure/container and add, edit, or delete entries. Then you'll need a little function to loop through your container and construct the full WHERE statement as well.

But just remember, a class is going to do very little for you in this case. Yes, it will let you encapsulate and hide some of the underlying mechanisms. For example, when you add a criteria it will get appended to some kind of private container/structure/variable that your calling code will not have to know about. And then when you call the Get method, once again, your calling code shouldn't need to know how the criteria is being stored, fabricated, etc. But you should be able to make all of this work without a class too, although it will be a lot more "loose", and certainly less than ideal.

Comment: I like your idea about the container object and storing the WHERE in it, could you expand on how that would work with a private variable within the class? That way it is a bit easier to manipulate in an `execute` function that would build everything and execute. This module will (Hopefully_ be copied to many programs in the future, and thus my desire to simplify it using an object > getter/setter. That way programmers aren't forced to learn how LDAP queries work and how to manipulate them.

Answer (score 0):

There is another thing I'm not sure you are aware of, but which may as well be very useful for you; perhaps it may even be what you are looking for in the end.

It is true that it is not very useful to use a class module for this, since there is no real use in creating multiple instances of this object.
However, you can make a standard module behave like an equivalent of what they call a 'static class' in C#, although VBA doesn't implement the concept of static classes.

Consider for a moment this definition for a static class in C#:

> A static class is basically the same as a non-static class, but there is one difference: a static class cannot be instantiated. In
> other words, you cannot use the new keyword to create a variable of
> the class type. Because there is no instance variable, you access the
> members of a static class by using the class name itself. For example,
> if you have a static class that is named UtilityClass that has a
> public method named MethodA, you call the method as shown in the
> following example:
>
> ```
> C#
> UtilityClass.MethodA();
> ```

As a proof of this concept, try out the following thing:
Put this identical code into two standard modules and call them `m_Class` and `m_Class2`:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Number As Long

Public Function store_number(value As Long)

m_Number = value

End Function

Public Function get_number()

get_number = m_Number

End Function
```

Now, create a third standard module that stores the following two subs:

```
Sub test()


m_Class.store_number (10)
m_Class2.store_number (5)

End Sub

Sub test_2()

MsgBox (m_Class.get_number)
MsgBox (m_Class2.get_number)

End Sub
```

What I wanted to indicate with this test, is that both standard modules are in fact two separate instances with their own private property, each implementing the same function.
So you'll notice that a standard module behaves very much like a static class (although its internal underlying mechanics are not the same).

I would advise you to create a standard module and implement this logic.
I do think that it is useful to create such a 'static' class since as you mentioned, you will re-use it a lot, while you will not need multiple instances of the class.